# Sistema de login em java

Tags: java, mysql

Então eu fiz esse código mas não ta passando, cai direto no else mesmo com usuario e senha corretos.

Fiz as alterações e instanciei a classe onde esta o método checkLogin, mas quando executo e boto os dados ele dá que os dados estão incorretos mesmo os dados estando corretos

BTNLOGAR

```
   package login;

    import cadastro.TelaCadastro;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import view.TelaPrincipal;
    import model.dao.UsuarioDAO;

    public class TelaLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public TelaLogin() {
            initComponents();

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            txt_user = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txt_senha = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            campo_usuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            campo_senha = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
            btn_logar = new javax.swing.JButton();
            btn_cadastrar = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

            txt_user.setText("Usuario:");

            txt_senha.setText("Senha:");

            campo_usuario.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    campo_usuarioActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            btn_logar.setText("Entrar");
            btn_logar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btn_logarActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            btn_cadastrar.setText("Cadastrar");
            btn_cadastrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btn_cadastrarActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
            jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
            jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(txt_senha)
                                .addComponent(txt_user))
                            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(campo_senha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 110, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(campo_usuario))
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                            .addComponent(btn_logar)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 89, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(btn_cadastrar)
                            .addGap(85, 85, 85))))
            );
            jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(115, 115, 115)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(txt_user)
                        .addComponent(campo_usuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(txt_senha)
                        .addComponent(campo_senha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btn_logar)
                        .addComponent(btn_cadastrar))
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35))
            );

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void campo_usuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                             

        private void btn_logarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

           //instancie a classe onde está o checkLogin, pois ele pedia para criar um metodo checkLogin e o metodo já existe

            UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();

       String strUsuario = campo_usuario.getText();
       String strSenha = new String(campo_senha.getPassword());

    if(dao.checkLogin(strUsuario, strSenha)){

    TelaPrincipal tela = new TelaPrincipal();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    dispose();


}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados incorretos!");
}

        }                                         

        private void btn_cadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
           new TelaCadastro().setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }                                             

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>


            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new TelaLogin().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton btn_cadastrar;
        private javax.swing.JButton btn_logar;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField campo_senha;
        private javax.swing.JTextField campo_usuario;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel txt_senha;
        private javax.swing.JLabel txt_user;

    }
```

verifica login

```
public boolean checkLogin(String email, String senha){

    Connection con = Conexao.getConnection(); 
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean check = false;


    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cadastro_user WHERE email = ?, and senha = ?");
        stmt.setString(1, email);
        stmt.setString(2, senha);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()){

          check = false;

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getEmail()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        Conexao.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
    }        
    return check;

}
```

Comment: Seu if só vai ser acionado quando os dois campos estiverem em branco. Esse metodo checkLogin não foi mostrado o uso dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há um problema com a lógica do `if`, somente cairá dentro dele quando ambos os campos forem em branco.

Outro problema é com seu método `checkLogin`, ele jamais retornará true. Ao invés de checar se o campo veio em branco ainda na tela, deixe essa responsabilidade para este método, já que sua finalidade é checar login, o que implica também verificar se as informações estão vindo em branco.

É desnecessário verificar se um campo está em branco, uma vez que você não irá guardar um login e senha em branco no seu banco, mas se o objetivo e evitar alocação de recursos de comunicação com o banco, reforça mais ainda a ideia de checar isso no método.

Com as alterações sugeridas, o código agora ficaria assim:

```
String strUsuario = campo_usuario.getText().trim();
String strSenha = new String(campo_senha.getPassword()).trim();

if(checkLogin(strUsuario, strSenha)){

    TelaPrincipal tela = new TelaPrincipal();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    dispose();


}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados incorretos!");
}
```

E o método `checklogin`:

```
public boolean checkLogin(String email, String senha){

    Connection con = Conexao.getConnection(); 
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean check = false;

    if(!email.isEmpty() && !senha.isEmpty()) {

        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cadastro_user WHERE email = ?, and senha = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, email);
            stmt.setString(2, senha);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()){

              check = true;

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getEmail()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
        Conexao.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
        }

    }

    return check;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não existe essa vírgula depois de email = ?
stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cadastro_user WHERE email = ?, and senha = ?");

Fica assim
stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cadastro_user WHERE email = ? and senha = ?");